# ValueError: gbrt has to be an instance of BaseGradientBoosting

Tags: python, dependencies, data-science, data-analysis, xgboost

So I am trying to make partial dependence plot using xgboost in spyder. But it is giving **ValueError: gbrt has to be an instance of BaseGradientBoosting**. I have predefine values of train_X, train_y, val_X, val_y.
Here is the code:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

model=XGBRegressor(n_estimator=1000, learning_rate=0.05)
model.fit(train_X, train_y, early_stopping_rounds=5, eval_set=[(val_X, val_y)], verbose=False)

pred_xgb=model.predict(val_X)

print(mean_absolute_error(pred_xgb, val_y),'is the mae \n')

from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import plot_partial_dependence
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import partial_dependence

plot=plot_partial_dependence(model,train_X, features=[1,3], feature_names=['mssubclass','mszoning','salestype','salescondition'], grid_resolution=20)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an incompatibility between sklearn and xgboost.

[plot_partial_dependence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence.plot_partial_dependence.html) expects a model that inherits from `BaseGradientBoosting` that is a sklearn-specific class that XGBoostRegressor does not inherit from AFAIK.

That means that if you want to use that you would need to convert between the XGBoost model and an sklearn GBRT model. It might be possible to do that through [treelite](https://treelite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, I have to use GradientBoostingRegressor instead XGBRegressor for plotting.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if you feel it addresses your question.